# How to maintain order of packets if multiple threads are processing in parallel?

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, pthreads

I am working on improving the performance of a network application written in C running on linux systems.

The program as it is written now it reads a packet from a socket interface, it does some processing on it and then it adds it to a send queue.

I am pretty new to multi threading programming but I am familiar with the basic concepts (mutex, conditional signals etc).
I am trying to implement a solution where a set of worker threads are passed what is read from the interface and they do the work that follows.

My question is how could I ensure that, if first thread reads the first packet and the second thread reads the second packet, the order in which the packets are added to the send queue are in the same order as read.

Comment: That kind of contradicts the whole point of working in parallel, doesn't it?

Comment: The receiving thread should sort the packets, not the workers.

Comment: a lot of time is wasted with the processing part so if multiple packets are processed in parallel then time would be saved...my question is how to add the result in the same order as read...considering the processing time is approximately constant

Comment: Your data flow is a bit unclear.  You have one thread reading packets, yes?  The packets get queued up, yes?  Processing threads get packets from the queue and work on them, yes?  OK, what happens to the packets once the processing threads have worked on them?   Where do they go?

Comment: I mean, it would be pretty easy to add a sequence number to the packet struct and then use a thread-safe container to store up out-of-sequence packets until all previous packets arrive.

Comment: @MartinJames yes you are correct...then the packets must be added to another queue. My original idea was to read like 8 packets first, add them to a vector of buffers and each thread reads from a fixed position and then add the processed packets to another vector of buffers in the same position...the reading thread waits for this and then from that it adds to the sending queue...but this seems far from optimal

Comment: The reading thread should just wait until the next packet is ready. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - the receiving thread does not know what packet will arrive next, so it will get packets out-of-order, so it must store them until the earlier packets get in.

Comment: As I see it, it's just like TCP, where packets arrive by different routes, out-of-order, but must be supplied in order to the application layer.

Comment: @MartinJames yes that was my analogy also...

Comment: The sender cannot wait - it should shove valid packets onto the processing queue as soon as they are available, complete with incrementing sequence-number, so that the processing threads can get at them.  The receiving thread can manage a list of any out-of-order packets.  When a packet comes in, the receiver can then iterate the list, looking for any stored out-of-order packets that should be released first before the newly-arrived one is released.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to solve this.  Different ways have different trade offs.  Things to consider are if you want to have a static number of worker threads, how many worker threads, and how perfect you want the solution to be.

If all worker threads are to receive their data packets directly via a call to `read` or `recv` then:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&the_mutex);
do
{
    read_size = read(sock, buf, buf_size);
    if (read_size > 0)
    {
        my_count = ++packet_counter;
        break;
    } else
    {
        // figure out how to handle different failures here
    }
} while (1);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&the_mutex);

results = do_work(buf, read_size);
enqueue_results(my_count, results);
```

Would work, where `enqueue_results()` would put the results into a priority queue that can handle wrapping around of the key (which isn't that difficult to do since you just order by `last_sent_count-this_count` rather than using this_count directly for the queue ordering).
Then another thread would needs to wait on the next reply to be sent to become ready and send that.

You could get a lot fancier, but you should give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

Just code what you want. Outbound packets can be inserted into a queue in order, and the sender can wait if the packet it needs to send next isn't at the head of the queue.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you add it to the send queue, does another thread that you have control over remove it from this send queue to later send or is this outside your control.  If the former you can use a [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) for the second queue instead of a traditional first in first out queue.  If the key to the priority queue is some global counter, the sender will always pull the smallest/next value.  Now if that smallest value isn't the next value you can have the thread pulling from the sender thread wait for the next value.  Depending on the priority queue implementation you can also just peek into the queue to see the next value and then conditionally wait until another insertion into the queue.

Answer (score 0):

The program could use separate receive and send queues for each thread. The receiving thread would queue packets to the processing threads in round robin order. Each processing thread would dequeue a packet from its receive queue, process the packet and queue the processed packet to its send queue. The sending thread would dequeue processed packets from the processed send queues in round robin order.